# using a scanner array to point to different files

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a scanner array `Scanner[] properties = new Scanner[number];` and was wondering if i can change the read path for just `properties[1]` and `properties[2]` etc.

I have a folder with a few different files in it, all of them use the same basic layout, can i get `properties[1]` to read from file `fire` and `properties[2]` to read from file `water`.

Comment: Don't see why not. Just try it. Should work fine. But then you would have 2 scanners, one for each file. Is that what you want?

Comment: But i dont know how to get properties[1] to read from Fire and properties[2] to read from Water

Comment: @user1610541 Show us what have you tired?

Comment: See javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: I don't think it's possible to change the source of a `Scanner`, but why not just reassign `properties[1]` and `properties[2]` to new `Scanner`s?

Comment: Make sure your array indices start at `0`.

Comment: properties[0] = new Scanner(new File("Fire")); properties[1] = new Scanner(new File("Water"));

Comment: Is there any reason not to read one file at a time?

Comment: Because I've got one scanner, scanning a file with names in it, then i'm using this array to find a file with that name and use options from it, it's so users can add different elements to the program without actually programming them in :)

Comment: @user1610541 Technically you'd probably take a bit of a performance hit by alternating reading from different files (in terms of seek time on your hard drive), but unless you've got a very high performance requirement, you probably won't even notice. If you're storing the required data in any way, you might as well read the whole first file into memory before you read any of the others.